# How to disable AT&T/enable Intel syntax in lazarus debug window?

Tags: assembly, pascal, disassembly, lazarus, intel-syntax

By default Lazarus shows x86/x64 assembly using the awful (horrible) AT&T syntax.

How do I make it display the Intel syntax that sane people use?

[image]

Comment: AT&T rockz, some people have no taste :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luckily there is an option.

Goto tools->Options->Debugger->General

[image]

In the section **Debugger_Startup_Options** paste:
 `-eval-command="set disassembly-flavor intel"`

Restart lazarus and sanity has been restored.

[image]

Much better....

Comment: This didn't work for me (under Linux). It complained about the quotes with a cryptic message. After several failed attempts, I was able to make it obey my `$HOME/.gdbinit`, which has that command in it, by adding: `-x /home/pgimeno/.gdbinit` and that worked.